# What mean in the layout description the "$" character conca two components?

Tags: android, custom-controls

I have see this character in a View description in the next code...the view is building using 2 custom components but I am looking for a explanation about this:

```
<view 
        class="com.icemobile.staatsloterij.ui.component.CustomCarousel$CustomViewFlipper" 
        android:id="@+id/carousel_flipper" 
        android:layout_width="275dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomViewFlipper` is a inner class in `CustomCarousel`. `$` it's the way to reference that class(because the java compiler will generate the name `CustomCarusel$CustomViewFlipper` for the `CustomViewFlipper`  class).

Answer (score 0):

java static member class

CustomViewFlipper is CustomCarousel's static inner class

Comment: Ok, I got it! But my programming knowledges are not enough to know what mean that  CustomViewFlipper is a static inner class of CustomCarousel's and why i have to reference this static class in the layout description.

Comment: sorry，I'm wrong，static member class is just Static Nested Classes ,not inner class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html